# How can you fake geolocation in Firefox?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, firefox, geolocation

Google and many other sites know my correct location. How can I fake my location without using a VPN, proxy, Tor or similar?

I went to `about:config` and looked for geo. What I think I have to modify is `geo.wifi.uri`? Maybe we can put in false lattitude and longitude values directly? If so, how would it look then? I really have no idea about the format.

Or is there another way using JavaScript in Greasemonkey?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Faking the Geolocation

You can spoof the location provided via the [HTML5 Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) this way:

- Go to `about:config`.
- Type in `geo.provider.network.url` (or `geo.wifi.uri` in older versions)
- Change the value to something like this:

  ```
  data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 40.7590, "lng": -73.9845}, "accuracy": 27000.0}
  ```

  (The `lat` and `lng` values determine the latitude and longitude of your location.
- Confirm that `geo.enabled` is `true`.
- You may also need to set `geo.provider.testing` to `true`. (Create the key if it doesn't exist.)
- Congratulations, you're now on Times Square! (Verify the result [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation).)

**Note:** This does not stop websites from deriving the location from your IP address. You can't do that on the application layer and would have to go with a proxy instead.

### Disabling the Geolocation

For privacy reasons, you may want to prevent use of the API entirely:

- Go to `about:config` and set `geo.enabled` to `false`.

### Some technical details

The Geolocation service in Firefox is set up in [`dom/geolocation/Geolocation.cpp`](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/geolocation/Geolocation.cpp). Following [`nsGeolocationService::Init()`](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/08bd4e9a7b2cda36f26b5c94fdcc5bd802e9114c/dom/geolocation/Geolocation.cpp#471-532) you see that without `geo.enabled`, the API initialization is aborted right away:

```
  if (!StaticPrefs::geo_enabled()) {
    return NS_ERROR_FAILURE;
  }
```

Further, the browser chooses between different location providers based on your platform and settings. As you see, there are prefs to switch them individually (e.g., if you're on MacOS,  you can set `geo.provider.use_corelocation` to `false` to disable geolocating via Apple's [Core Location API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation)):

```
#ifdef MOZ_WIDGET_ANDROID
  mProvider = new AndroidLocationProvider();
#endif

#ifdef MOZ_WIDGET_GTK
#  ifdef MOZ_GPSD
  if (Preferences::GetBool("geo.provider.use_gpsd", false)) {
    mProvider = new GpsdLocationProvider();
  }
#  endif
#endif

#ifdef MOZ_WIDGET_COCOA
  if (Preferences::GetBool("geo.provider.use_corelocation", true)) {
    mProvider = new CoreLocationLocationProvider();
  }
#endif

#ifdef XP_WIN
  if (Preferences::GetBool("geo.provider.ms-windows-location", false) &&
      IsWin8OrLater()) {
    mProvider = new WindowsLocationProvider();
  }
#endif

  if (Preferences::GetBool("geo.provider.use_mls", false)) {
    mProvider = do_CreateInstance("@mozilla.org/geolocation/mls-provider;1");
  }
```

Only if none of the platform-specific providers apply, or if `geo.provider.testing` is `true`, Firefox defaults to the network (URL-based) provider:

```
  if (!mProvider || Preferences::GetBool("geo.provider.testing", false)) {
    nsCOMPtr<nsIGeolocationProvider> geoTestProvider =
        do_GetService(NS_GEOLOCATION_PROVIDER_CONTRACTID);

    if (geoTestProvider) {
      mProvider = geoTestProvider;
    }
  }
```

The network provider ([`dom/system/NetworkGeolocationProvider.jsm`](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/system/NetworkGeolocationProvider.jsm)) then requests the URL specified in `geo.provider.network.url`. You could set up your own mock HTTP location serivce and enter its URL here. But more easily, as in the steps at the top, it's sufficient use a `data:` pseudo URI to mimic a network provider that unconditionally responds with your desired location details.

Comment: Technically, you can often spoof geoip information directly without using a proxy, but that usually requires the IP being on an autonomous service which you have at least some influence over.

Comment: This requires restarting Firefox. And please change that w3schools link to MDN or anything else!

Comment: In my version of Firefox (108) I also had to set `geo.provider.use_geoclue` to `false`

Answer (score 5):

On Firefox 102+, the Geoclue2 geolocation provider is now [used by default](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1769664).

For the `geo.provider.network.url` override to work, you must first set the setting `geo.provider.use_geoclue` to `false`.

The following additional options were also set to enable location spoofing on firefox 110.0.1:

```
geo.prompt.testing: true
geo.prompt.testing.allow: true
geo.provider.testing: true
```

After setting these options, Firefox must be restarted for them to take effect. Then, the `geo.provider.network.url` setting will function as it used to.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your traffic is going directly to them (that is, not through a proxy of some sort), they will have your IP and thus a rough geographic location.

Comment: Geolocation is a particular web API, I assume OP doesn't want to hide the IP but trick that API.

Comment: @Arminius I think it is unclear if the question is about "the HTML5 geolocation API" or just "any geolocation techniques in general".