# How would you hide your tracks/location without Tor or a VPN yourself?

Tags: privacy, vpn, tor

This is kinda similar to this question, [How can you hide / fake your ip address without proxy / vpn?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147262/how-can-you-hide-fake-your-ip-address-without-proxy-vpn), but this was about particular tools and their effectiveness. What I'm wondering is how someone would configure their internet connection, programmatically, to mask their location as effectively as Tor and VPNs?

Comment: Tor, VPN, anonymous proxies etc are there for a reason. You are essentially asking how to achieve your goal without using any of the tools which were designed to achieve the goal. This is like asking how to get to the internet without an internet provider.

Comment: i'm just asking this because i remember hearing how that before tor you could relay your connection but there was a lot of configuration involved, or maybe look at different angles for hiding your connection. I'm not asking a senseless or redundant question as you seem to be implying.

Comment: Maybe you've heard about hackers using chains of compromised systems they controlled in order hide their real location when attacking other systems. This is basically like a chains of proxies (not necessarily web proxies though).

Comment: yeah that's a possibility, and im aware an IP address is an inseparable part of any network device that could reveal the location of the device. However, i'm skeptical of the notion that i would need to compromise other systems or use tor/vpn/proxy server in order to throw someone off.

Comment: You don't need to hack into other systems but could instead use VPN, proxies,Tor and similar technologies. But there is not just some magical change on the configuration of your internet access which does not involve any of such technologies. Maybe if you remember more details of what you've heard one could give you more details but *"relay your connection"* sounds very much like proxies or other kind of tunnels (SSH, via hacked systems, Tor..)